# Ionic/AngularJS $resource Timeout Config Setting Not Working

Tags: angularjs, get, ionic-framework, resources, timeout

I've been trying to setup a timeout value (in milliseconds) for my $resource so that if the server doesn't respond within 10*1000 milliseconds, I want the service in my factory to return the error promise.

I have a factory with the following method:

```
service.getDelta = $resource(BASE_API_URL + '/delta/:inTable/:inDate', 
{inTable: '@inTable', inDate: '@inDate'},
{query: {timeout: 10*1000}});
```

In the controller I do the following:

```
getDataPromises.push(remoteService.getDelta.query({inTable: "table1", inDate: clientDateLastModified}).$promise);
getDataPromises.push(remoteService.getDelta.query({inTable: "table2", inDate: clientDateLastModified}).$promise);
getDataPromises.push(remoteService.getDelta.query({inTable: "table3", inDate: clientDateLastModified}).$promise);
getDataPromises.push(remoteService.getDelta.query({inTable: "table4", inDate: clientDateLastModified}).$promise);
```

Then I check to ensure all are successful or handle error if one fails.

```
$q.all(getDataPromises).then(
  function (result) {
    // NOTIFY SUCCESS
  },
  function (error) {
    // NOTIFY ERROR
  });
```

The success in the promise has been coming through as expected. If I leave out the timeout config, I also get the error in the promise for issues like 404. But when I add the timeout, I get the following when I stringify the error object in my error callback:

```
{"line":13380,"column":32,"sourceURL":"file:///Users/ ... /www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"}
```

Am I misunderstanding the use of the timeout property?

I am using ionic 1.2.4 which I believe is using Angular 1.4.3.

Note: I know this use case doesn't justify use of $resource and could be done with $http, but I wanted to get to get a feel for using it since I plan to down the road for this app.

Thanks!